# R: find row and column where one variable exceeds all others until last row

Tags: r

I have data like this (generated by a program rather than by hand, but this is to serve as an example):

```
a<-c(10,12,18,25,24,26,26,26,22,21)
b<-c(12,14,14,24,27,26,26,25,20,18)
x<-c(12,18,20,18,16,14,18,18,20,20)
d<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,x))


d
    a  b  x
1  10 12 12
2  12 14 18
3  18 14 20
4  25 24 18
5  24 27 16
6  26 26 14
7  26 26 18
8  26 25 18
9  22 20 20
10 21 18 20
```

I want to find out which of the 3 variables 'wins', where winning means to have higher value than any other variable from some row until the final row. So in this example, d$a wins, because it has the row-wise maximum value from row 8 onwards -- even though the maximum overall value occurs for d$b at row 6.

So the answer I'd be looking for here would be that d$a wins because it 'dominates' from row 8 onwards.

I can do this with loops, but the reason I'm switching to R is to get away from that approach. Also, the real data has several hundred columns and a few thousand rows, so loops would be quite slow. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Note that the maximum overall value for `d$b` does not occur at row six but at row five!

Answer (score 2):

Compute per-row maximum values

```
> m<-apply(d,1,max)
> m
 [1] 12 18 20 25 27 26 26 26 22 21
```

Now `d==m` tells you which cells equal the maximum per row

```
> d==m
          a     b     x
 [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [9,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[10,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

So the idea is to see what column has the last `FALSE` closest to the top. That is the one that wins (I think this is what you mean).

```
# Per-column last row index that equals FALSE
> d2<-apply(d==m,2,function(x){rev(which(x==F))[1]})
> d2
 a  b  x 
 5 10 10
```

Now you have the column that wins (`a`) and from what row (`5`). You can get them like this:

```
o<-order(d2)
win.row<-d2[o[1]]
win.col<-o[1]
win.colname<-names(win.row)
```

Comment: Thank you, Julián. This is tantalizingly close and very instructive! I can see that a wins, and does so after row 5, but where I'm stuck is how I now act on / extract the relevant information in d2. I think a general way to do that would be if I knew how to identify the row, column, and value of the element in a vector or matrix holding the minimum value. Do you happen to know how to do that?

Comment: Julián's answer provides a great solution. However, I realized that for this example, the desired answer would actually be row 8 for a -- that is the row where a not only has the row maximum value, but it is greater than all other columns. I'm spinning my wheels trying to figure this out... Any advice?

Comment: Ah, I found a solution. Use `o` to drop the 'winner' column (`db <- d[,c(o[-1])]`), then find the max of the remaining columns (`mb <- apply(db,1,max)`), and find then the LAST column where the winner does NOT exceed all others (`dwin <- apply(t(d[,o[1]] > mb),1,function(x){rev(which(x==F))[1]})`). Thanks again, Julián -- I continue to learn from this solution!

Comment: @user20412 best way to say thanks is to accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, although I have a feeling I not understand your question correctly -

```
whichrow <- 8

gsub(
  x = names(
    which.max(
      unlist(
        d[whichrow:nrow(d),]
        )
      )
    ), 
  pattern = '[[:digit:]]', 
  replacement = ''
  )
```

For your whole dataset, you could run something like this -

```
d[,"whichmax"] <- ""
for ( i in 1:10)
{
  d[i,"whichmax"] <- gsub(
  x = names(
    which.max(
      unlist(
        d[i:nrow(d),]
        )
      )
    ), 
  pattern = '[[:digit:]]', 
  replacement = ''
  )
}
```

The for-loop doesn't hurt in this case, is there some other reason you're avoiding the loop? The output from the second function is as under -

```
> d
    a  b  x whichmax
1  10 12 12        b
2  12 14 18        b
3  18 14 20        b
4  25 24 18        b
5  24 27 16        b
6  26 26 14        a
7  26 26 18        a
8  26 25 18        a
9  22 20 20        a
10 21 18 20        a
```

Comment: Nice -- this gives me 'whichmax', but what I'm trying to do is pretty nonintuitive and not quite that. Please see my response to dacannon below asking for clarification.

Comment: Actually, I was unable to add a comment to dacannon's post, so here's what I intended to say: The data are actually activations in a neural network. As in the example data, the 'winner' is the node that rises to the top rank and then stays there. So d$b temporarily achieves highest rank, but doesn't stay there. d$a achieves highest rank with a peak value less than d$b's, but then stays there (though the values for each column continue to decrease).

Comment: `whichmax` is actually the max amongst all elements of the remaining rows. So the fact that the latter rows on `whichmax` are all "a", would mean that "a" rose to the top and stayed there. Therefore "a" is your answer. What exactly is the clarification you're seeking?

Answer (score -1):

This gives you the column name with the maximum entry from row 8 onwards:

```
> rev(colnames(d)[order(apply(d[8:nrow(d),], 2, max))])[1]
[1] "a"
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Ah, in combination with Julián's answer above, I can do this to get the name of the column I need -- thanks!  `names(d2)[order(apply(t(d2),2,min))[1]]`